# Best way to add Foreign Key to massive table?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have 4 tables: `arrival` (~100 million rows), `departure` (~100 million rows), `airport` (~30 million rows), `airplane` (small).

`arrival` and `departure` each have 2 ForeignKeys: one to `airport`, one to `airplane`.

Currently, to figure out which planes are at an airport at a certain time, I have to do a massive join between `arrival`, `departure`, and `airport`. So, I'd like to add a (possibly NULL) ForeignKey to the `departure` table that points to the `arrival` of the same airplane that's departing.

Given that these tables are so big, it seems like a bad idea to do this all as a single transaction. So, what's the best way to go about it?

Comment: Me wonders. Are there really 30 million airports in the world?

Comment: I never said this was real-world data. :)

Comment: Unfortunately PostgreSQL doesn't support lazy / concurrent foreign key creation, where you create the key, then validate it in the background. It's something I'd love to build, but don't have the time and funding for.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, depending not just on the number of rows but also on the total size of your table (based on the average row size) , *it may not be excessive to create a new Foreign Key*. Especially if scheduled properly.

However, it may well be too **heavy** a change.  In that case, you could consider creating an Intersection Table like:

```
CREATE TABLE FlightPair
(
     departurekey INT REFERENCES arrival NULL,
     arrivalkey INT REFERENCES departure NULL
)
```

This would allow you to incrementally batch the insert of rows into the intersection table a bit at a time, thus keeping the update transactions quite small.  Perhaps insert one day at a time, 10,000 rows at a time, or some other batching method.  Each batch should be a transaction that begins before the insert/update and commits when finished.

That means that the updating of the batches of your choice would be many small transactions instead of one big one.  That would limit the resources needed and, in many cases, would run faster that one big update.

Perhaps having a `date` included would help to filter the results more effectively.  NULL keys are probably needed for the periods that are incomplete.

What indexes do you currently have?  SQL performance issues often depend on having the indexes properly defined. The columns in the intersection table likewise need to have indexes, as do the `departure` and `arrival` tables.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but I do indeed want to add the Foreign Key from `departure` to `arrival`. So, how should I go about populating the new FK field?

Comment: And it seems like it would take at least as long to populate your intersection table as it would to populate a new FK.

Comment: Updated the post to respond to your comments.

Comment: I have the indexes necessary for all my SELECTs to run quickly. You can assume in your answer that I have all necessary indexes defined. (If I don't, I'll be able to figure that out myself once I draw up a solution.)

Comment: What worries me is not the performance of each UPDATE, but just the fact that I have to do so many of them. It seems like a bad idea to do them all in a single transaction. If I do use a single transaction, won't that take a ton of memory, since it has to continuously keep track of the state before the commit so it can roll back if needed?

Comment: @MikeS. Regarding the updates the small batches should be inside a transaction.  Updating 100 million rows will require more resources than many small updates.

Comment: For clarity:  EACH batch of updates should be inside a single transaction which is committed at the end of the batch.